# QThreadPool strange exception

Tags: c++, qt, exception

I was "messing" with threadpools and I noticed a strange exception. So I'm here to ask you: am i using this object correctly? Or you think it is just a bug or a dummy warning?
Here it is. I implemented a basic example with QThreadPool (it's almost the same as the one in the documentation: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/thread-basics.html#example-1-using-the-thread-pool).

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QTimer>
#include <QRunnable>
#include <QThreadPool>
#include <QDebug>
class Work : public QRunnable
{
public:
    void run()
    {
        qDebug() << "Hello from thread " << QThread::currentThread();
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication app(argc, argv);
    Work work;
    work.setAutoDelete(false);
    QThreadPool *threadPool = QThreadPool::globalInstance();
    threadPool->start(&work);
    qDebug() << "hello from GUI thread " << QThread::currentThread();
    threadPool->waitForDone();
    QTimer::singleShot(3000, &app, SLOT(quit()));
    return app.exec();
}
```

If i launch the debugger in the status bar where it shows messages such as "Running" and "Debugger finished." it tells me:

```
Exception at 0x75f6812f, code: 0x406d1388: Startup complete, flags 0x0 (first chance) in KERNELBASE!RaiseException
```

The program works, because it writes the correct things and do not hang, but that message is strange for me.

Am I doing something wrong?

Thank you

Comment: I tried your example here with Qt 4.8.6 and 5.3.1. I Also got an exception in 4.8.6 (5.3.1 is doing fine). However, doing development with QT creator over the last few years I also encounter these kinds of strange exceptions from time to time and never found out why (but they also didin't break anything in my applications)..

Comment: can you try using `QThreadPool` after the event loop is started?

Comment: using the threadpool in the event loop behaves the same. The "problem" is... Microsoft. They invented this two step exception handling, and every time an exception is thrown the "first chance exception" is thrown. Even if it is properly handled. So, like Kuba said, there is nothing to worry about ;)

@TWE : probably it behaves differently because you use two different debuggers (msvc for 4.8.6 and mingw(gdb) for 5.3.1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a first chance exception. It is obviously caught and dealt with by the code, since otherwise your application would have crashed. So it's not a problem.

Comment: Good to know. I didn't know this "first chance exception" stuff; this "line" is written every time an exception in code is thrown, even if it is properly handled.
So.. Thank you!